# Run Time Analysis: Correct my examples on Why these loops have O(log n) Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I was doing analysis of loops and got these following loops:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i *= c) {
       // some expressions
   }

 for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= c) {
       // some expressions
   }
```

I understand that the loop growth rate is log n (base c)
But I am stuck while doing some test examples such as below:

Loop-1:
if c = 2 and n = 8 then

loop runs true for i= 1,2,4,8 (4 times) **BUT log 8 = 3 ? [should be 4]**

Loop-2:
if c = 2 and n = 8 then

loop runs true for i= 8,4,2,1 (4 times) **BUT log 8 = 3 ? [should be 4]**

Where i did the mistake.please help me to match the results with Time rate Log n. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O notation is always an approximation, or better a worst case limit. For example `O(logN)=O(logN+X)`, when X is a constant.
In your example the precise iterations  of your for loop is `logN+1`, which means
it is `O(logN+1)=O(logN)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best possible answer from an academic reference:

[image]

Source: http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt